# Need help writing query that inserts a new row drawing its data from two rows under the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I am writing a data fix SQL script that is to insert a new record using data from two rows that are under the same ID.

My table looks like the following:

```
AccountID | ActivityId | Debit | Credit | DisplayDetails | TransactionDate
=========================================================================
1   1   100 0   Display Details1    2015-02-02 
1   2   0   0   Display Details1    2018-02-02 
1   1   300 0   Display Details1    1999-02-02 
1   2   0   0   Display Details1    2000-02-02 
2   1   200 0   Display Details2    2017-02-02 
2   2   0   0   Display Details2    2017-04-06 
2   12  0   200 Display Details2    2015-04-06 
3   1   200 0   Display Details3    2015-02-04 
3   3   0   200 Display Details3    2015-06-02 
4   1   100 0   Display Details4    2016-02-02 
4   2   0   0   Display Details4    2016-06-02
```

ActivityId 1 writes to Debit

ActivityId 2 writes to neither, but is needed in my conditions

ActivityId 3 writes to Credit

ActivityId 12 writes to Credit

My data fix is to find ActivityId 1 with an associated ActivityId 2 but NOT an associated 12 or 3 under the same AccountID.

I have written a query that meets these conditions:

```
SELECT A.AccountID 
INTO #temp
FROM Account A WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE ActivityId IN (1, 2, 3, 12)
GROUP BY A.AccountID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN A.ActivityId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.ActivityId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.ActivityId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.ActivityId = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Now that I have the affected data, I need to insert a new record with ActivityId 12 using DisplayDetails from the associated Accounts ActivityId 2 and TransactionDate from ActivityId 1. 
I also need to insert to field Credit using the Debit value from ActivityId 1.

The background behind this is each Activity 1 and 2 under the same AccountId SHOULD have an ActivityId 12 too, however some of these were missed, hence the need for this fix script.

Below is my approach:

```
-- Uses AccountIds retrieved above to then get data from parent table.
SELECT A.AccountID, A.ActivityId, A.DebitAmount, A.CreditAmount, A.DisplayDetails, A.TransactionDate
INTO #temp2 
FROM Account A
JOIN #temp T
    ON T.AccountID = A.AccountID

-- Get ActivityId 2 data 
SELECT * 
INTO #ActivityTwo
FROM #temp2 T
WHERE T.ActivityId = 2

INSERT INTO Account (AccountID, ActivityId, DebitAmount, CreditAmount, DisplayDetails, TransactionDate)
SELECT T.AccountID, 12, 0, T.DebitAmount, S.DisplayDetails, T.TransactionDate
FROM #temp2 T WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN #ActivityTwo S
    ON T.AccountID = S.AccountID
WHERE T.ActivityId = 1
```

However if I have multiple Activity 1 and Activity 2 under the same AccountId, my script inserts duplicate rows.

```
AccountID | ActivityId | Debit | Credit | DisplayDetails | TransactionDate
=========================================================================
1   1   100 0   Display Details1    2015-02-02 
1   2   0   0   Display Details1    2018-02-02 
1   1   300 0   Display Details1    1999-02-02 
1   2   0   0   Display Details1    2000-02-02 
1   12  0   100 Display Details1    2015-02-02 
1   12  0   100 Display Details1    2015-02-02 
1   12  0   300 Display Details1    1999-02-02 
1   12  0   300 Display Details1    1999-02-02 
2   1   200 0   Display Details2    2017-02-02 
2   2   0   0   Display Details2    2017-04-06 
2   12  0   200 Display Details2    2015-04-06 
3   1   200 0   Display Details3    2015-02-04 
3   3   0   200 Display Details3    2015-06-02 
4   1   100 0   Display Details4    2016-02-02 
4   2   0   0   Display Details4    2016-06-02 
4   12  0   100 Display Details4    2016-02-02
```

As you can see, AccountID 1 has 4 extra 12 records, when it should only have two 12 records.

AccountID 4 worked correctly though, so I believe the problem lies with an account having multiple ActivityId 1 and 2s.

Why is this happening? What can I do to fix this?

Does anyone have a better approach to this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have any way to associate Activity 1 rows with Activity 2 rows, I think you need a SELECT DISTINCT on your second insert.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.AccountID, A.ActivityId, A.DebitAmount, A.CreditAmount, 
A.DisplayDetails, A.TransactionDate
INTO #temp2 
FROM Account A
JOIN #temp T
    ON T.AccountID = A.AccountID
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. The script is meant to insert once for each 5, 6 combination, but it appears to insert for 5 and 6 individually, resulting in duplicate rows

Comment: Say I did have a field that associated each activity 1 and 2 together, what modifications would I need to make?